# Angular 8 - Static link

Tags: angular

I have a HTML widget on Database that is printed in my page. In this HTML I need to provide a link to a specific route of my angular app.

I've tried to put:

```
<div (click)="goThere('1234')" style="cursor:pointer"> goto</div>
<a href="/param/1234"  >goto</a>
<a [routerlink]="/param/1234">goto</a>
```

where toThere is a function in page with "navigate" directive.

None of the solution above works (only href solution trigger the navigation but I lost the parameters). I suppose because its a code that "appears" realtime e not pre-parsed by angular.

My routing configuration:

```
 { path: ''                     ,  data: { breadcrumb: 'Home'} ,
  children: 
    [  
      {
        path      : '' , component : DashboardComponent , pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path      : 'param/:param' , component : DashboardComponent,
      }
    ] 
  },
```

In my DashboardComponent I've:

```
 const param = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('param');
    if (param > 0)
    {
       this.param = param;
    }
```

Is there a way to trigger angular router system or a way to go to Dashboard Component with my parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#/param/1234">goto</a>
```

You need to preserve your base URL so it's required to add `#` before the URL

Comment: Unfortunally routerlink is not triggered at all. I think its because its not an HTML know during "compiling" but its an HTML attached in realtime after a click event.

Comment: No triggering. I suppose any "angular attribute" is not parsed because is simply printed realtime.

Comment: remove the brackets and try again and if possible show me how it is rendering in the html  using browser inspection

Comment: The HTML is printed as it is originally. No parsing is done:

`<div (click)="goThere('1100001')" style="cursor:pointer"> test1 </div>
<a href="/param/1100001" style="cursor:pointer">test2</a><br>
<a [routerlink]="['param']" [queryparams]="{ param: 1100001}" style="cursor:pointer">test3</a><br>
<a [href]="#/param/1100001">test4</a> <br>
<a href="#/param/1100001">test5</a><br>`

Imagine it as a function that put some HTML with InnerHTML

Comment: remove brackets from href

Comment: I have written every possible version of href. Test2 has plain, test4 has brackets, test5 no brackets

Comment: is this your child module ? then u need to append the url of base module as well.

Comment: I came up with a very dirty solution but it works: 
`<div onClick="localStorage.setItem('param',1100001);location.href='/'" style="cursor:pointer"> test6 </div>`

IN DASHBOARD COMPONENT

`var param = localStorage.getItem('param');
    if (param !== null)
    {
       localStorage.removeItem('param');
       this._router.navigate(['/param/'+param]);
    }`

Comment: Only href should work i don't know why its not working.. try to move the empty route to the bottom, it should always come at the end of the routing array

Comment: The problem is the HTML that "appears" in the page and Angular treat it like a static HTML without "interpreting" it. So any angualar property is not converted in angular stuffs.